# Clang AST: How to parse nested namespace specifiers?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

```cpp
namespace na {
  namespace nb {
    namespace nc {
      int val;
    }
  }
}

na::nb::nc::val = 42;
```

Is there any way to retrieve all of nested namespace specifiers that precedes the `val` apartly (`na`, `nb` and `nc`)?

---

```cpp
bool VisitDeclRefExpr(clang::DeclRefExpr *DeclRef) {
  if (DeclRef->hasQualifier()) {
    clang::SourceLocation BeginLoc = DeclRef->getQualifierLoc().getBeginLoc(),
                          EndLoc = DeclRef->getQualifierLoc().getEndLoc();
    const char *begin = SourceManager.getCharacterData(BeginLoc),
               *end = SourceManager.getCharacterData(EndLoc);
    llvm::outs() << std::string(begin, end - begin) << "\n";
  }
  return true;
}
```

Code provides `na::nb::nc` as output that could be easily separated by `::` delimiter.

---

I hope to figure out how to solve it using `Clang` and `LLVM` API's only. What should I pay attention and look for? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but looking right next to `getQualifierLoc`, I see `getQualifier`, which returns a `NestedNameSpecifier`. Did that not work out?

Comment: It returns `na::`, `na::nb::` and `na::nb::nc:`. I would like to get `na`, `nb` and `nc` apartly.